# Cuando llamo a la propiedad de una relación de Muchos a Muchos no obtengo el resultado esperado

Tags: base-de-datos, laravel-5, eloquent, php7, relaciones

tengo la entidad InventoryMaster con la relación

```
public function alternates()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(self::class,
        'inventories_master_alternates',
        'inventory_master_id',
        'alternate_of_id');
}
```

cuando intento llamarla con php

```
InventoryMaster::find(5)->alternates
```

me devuelve un array vacio cuando deberia devolver al menos dos elementos.

Comment: Donde estas probando el codigo desde la controladora, navegando en la página o en una prueba unitaria???

Comment: estoy probando con Artisan Tinker de Laravel

Comment: podrías incluir el código de los modelos para ver si está bien hecha la relación

Comment: es una relación de muchos a muchos autoreferenciada, no es necesario otro modelo. `$this->belongsToMany(self::class` .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta probar creando en el archivo web de las rutas lo siguiente:

```
Route::get('/probando', function(){
    dd(InventoryMaster::find(4)->alternates);
});
```

Si te muestra cuando navegues a esa url **/probando**, el arreglo conteniendo los elementos que tienes relacionados en tu base de datos, probablemente sea entonces tema de que el tinker, no esta pendiente de los cambios que hicistes en tu entidad y necesites abrirlo nuevamente.

Comment: ya probé lo que me dijiste y obtengo los resultados cuando puse la url `/probando`. No se que me quieres decir con lo del tinker.

Comment: Si te funciona con la primera parte, quiere decir que si cierras el tinker de nuevo, y lo abres nuevamente y pones InventoryMaster::find(4)->alternates debe devolverte los resultados esperados. Si te funciona aceptala como respuesta correcta

Comment: Perfecto !!! no way!! no puedo creer que sea eso.